# No abre ventana Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bucles, while, hilos

tengo inconvenientes con mi código respecto a la ejecución de una ventana con Tkinter.

En simples palabras lo que quiero ejecutar es un bucle en que se mantiene constante buscando información en pantalla y realizar cierta acción al encontrar un elemento en pantalla. Y ahora deseo implementar una ventana de interfaz para que sea más amigable para el usuario.

Comparto el código que he escrito.

```
#Alerta de que el programa está corriendo
pyautogui.alert('El programa se está ejecutando')

#$#         INCIO CÓDIGO INTERFAZ DE LA VENTANA 1       #$#

    #VARIABLES DE LA VENTANA 1

#CREA VENTANA 1
ventana_1 = tk.Tk()
#NOMBRE DE LA VENTANA
ventana_1.title("MI ASISTENTE")
#DIMENSIONES Y POSICION EN PANTALLA DEL PROGRAMA
ventana_1.geometry("400x130+300+300") #Ancho x Alto + X + Y
#CONFIGURACIÓN DE COLOR
ventana_1.configure(background='honeydew')
        
#Funcion para capturar pantalla. Muestra la pantalla en vivo

def worker():
     monitor = pyautogui.screenshot("vivo.png")
     print("Se ha capturado la pantalla!")
     return monitor    

#Define la acción al encontrar la alerta en pantalla

def regla1():
     if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("alerta.PNG") == None:
          print("No se encuentra Alerta!")
     else:
          print("Alerta encontrada!")
          pyautogui.press("space")
regla = regla1()

def bucle():
     threads = []
     while regla == None:
          t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
          threads.append(t)
          t.start()
          w = threading.Thread(target=regla1)
          threads.append(w)
          w.start()
          time.sleep(1)
     else:
          pass
bucle()

#BOTÓN QUE FINALIZA EL PROGRAMA
boton_cerrar = tk.Button(ventana_1, text="CERRAR", command=ventana_1.destroy).place(x=100, y=70)
     
####            CREA UN LOOP INFINITO DE EJECUCIÓN DE LA VENTANA 1           ####
ventana_1.mainloop()
```

Como se muestra en la imagen, al ejecutar el código solo se ejecuta la función **bucle()** sin abrir la *ventana1* ya definida al inicio. He intentado cambiar el orden del código obteniendo el mismo resultado de la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado esperado: Que se abra la ventana mientras se ejecuta el bucle() en segundo plano y con el botón "CERRAR" para finalizar el bucle() y cerrar la ventana1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

El problema se debe a que el mainloop de Tkinter no se ejecuta hasta que termine el bucle while. Al parecer, el mainloop hace posible que se abra la ventana. Además, en ningún momento llamas al método update, que actualiza la ventana, procesa los eventos y la muestra.

#### Solución

Incluso si pusieras el método update dentro del while, tu interfaz andaría trabada debido a que el tiempo entre dos llamadas a update sería de poco mas que un segundo.

Lo mejor para este caso, y viendo que queres que el bucle se termine cuando se cierre la ventana y hay un time.sleep, sería el método [after](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/la-funcion-after-en-tkinter/), que programa para dentro de x tiempo (en milisegundos) la ejecución de una función.

###### Código (sin probar)

```
# Tu código anterior aquí

# Sacamos esta lista fuera de bucle, ya que si no será eliminada y creada de nuevo todo el tiempo.
# Fuera de la función, podrías mantener una lista de las tareas.
threads = []

def bucle():
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    w = threading.Thread(target=regla1)
    threads.append(w)
    w.start()

    if(regla == None):
        ventana_1.after(1000, bucle)

#BOTÓN QUE FINALIZA EL PROGRAMA
boton_cerrar = tk.Button(ventana_1, text="CERRAR", command=ventana_1.destroy).place(x=100, y=70)
     
bucle()

ventana_1.mainloop()
```

*Nota* Si la función bucle tarda mucho tiempo en ejecutarse, la ventana se va a trabar.